# Qode Theme - Loading too large images. How can I prevent this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to increase the pagespeed for the index page. We're using a masonry plugin that's included in the Bridge/ Qore themes masonry grid.

```
https://liesbulteel.beaudesign.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/LiesBulteel_Keramiek_UItnodigin_Kijkkoopmoment_juli2019-700x343.png is resized in HTML or CSS from 700x343 to 235x115. Serving a scaled image could save 367.8KiB (88% reduction).
```

Where can I change the 700px value? I tried changing it in the Media thumbnail settings.

Any idea where to start?

Comment: When you update the media thumbnail sizes you need to tickle Wordpress to regenerate the thumbnails.  Thumbnail generation is usually done when you upload a new file, so there is a bunch of plugins that force a regeneration.  Choose one of those.

Comment: Ok regenerating thumbnails.

Comment: This seems to have solved the issue. Thank you so much. Any tips for huge files like 4580px x 3450px pictures?

Comment: Define your [preferred image sizes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) in your themes. Then, when you call for an image, [call for the image by size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) rather than by a direct URL. You'll still store the original file in all it's resolute grand-ness but you'll be able to keep your image sizes lower for general usage.  Also review plugins like smush or imagemagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you've done everything right.  One last step is to regenerate the thumbnails, which Wordpress does not do automatically.  You'll want to find a plugin (of which there are a large number) to do that, and then the correct image will be displayed.